# why write async code in python while GIL exists?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, gil

I am wondering, if python GIL allow only a single thread / process to run at once, why should I use asyncio, I get that switching between threads is expensive but, thats it? this is the only advantage of asyncio in python?

Comment: The whole point of asyncio is that you don't _need_ multiple threads if you just multiplex efficiently in one. The GIL doesn't stop you from multiplexing, it only stops you from threading; so the GIL makes asyncio _more_ necessary by making threaded performance worse.

Comment: Are you under the impression that the GIL automatically makes thread-based code thread-safe? It doesn't. The GIL protects the Python interpreter itself, not your code.

Comment: ...I'm not sure I understand why you would think the GIL makes async unnecessary. Questions should be clear and explicit; we shouldn't need to guess at your meaning.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Taking about being clear and explicit...which "you" are you talking to?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, the OP, exclusively, when not explicitly addressing anyone else.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Then you should `@` them since there are multiple contributors on this page. Also, where did the OP state that "the GIL makes async unnecessary"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, that's my restatement of the best understanding I can make out of the question. If it's inaccurate, that's an opportunity for the OP to clarify what they _actually_ meant to say. In that context, understanding how someone fishing for meaning in their question might misinterpret it is hopefully helpful.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, btw, Stack Overflow automatically removes `@`s directed at the OP of a question or comment, _because that's the assumed target_. See a discussion on [meta] on the topic, at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment. (From that exchange you can gather that there's no small number of people who don't _like_ that behavior, but nonetheless, the site is designed with an assumption that `@`-ing the OP is unnecessary).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Threading in Python is inefficient because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (Global Interpreter Lock) which means that multiple threads cannot be run in parallel as you would expect on a multi-processor system. Plus you have to rely on the interpreter to switch between threads, this adds to the inefficiency.

**asyc/asyncio allows concurrency within a single thread. This gives you, as the developer, much more fine grained control of the task switching and can give much better performance for concurrent I/O bound tasks than Python threading.**

The 3rd approach that you don't mention is [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html). This approach uses processes for concurrency and allows programs to make full use of hardware with multiple cores.

Comment: I think a key thing to highlight is that `asyncio` is specifically meant to help when doing concurrent I/O. It allows you to have one thread send many (100s or 1000s) I/O requests at once, without ever blocking the thread. Normally you would need to have one thread per I/O request, which is costly in terms of memory usage and context switching (though it does not hold the GIL - Python releases the GIL during blocking I/O). If you're doing CPU-bound work that requires the GIL to be held, `asyncio` has no benefit at all, and `multiprocessing` is your best option to improve performance.